# Using sans-serif-condensed in compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I'm want to use sans-serif-condensed in jetpack compose, but for the life of me, I can't find it anywhere within compose itself?

Am I just blind, or will I need to do something like import the font and set it all manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `fontFamily` attribute to specify the font family.

```
Text("Hello World", fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif)
```

#### Predefined Fonts

By default, Jetpack compose has only 5 Font Families,
`Default`, `SansSerif`, `Serif`, `Monospace` and `Cursive`.

#### Custom Fonts

If you need any other font family (which seems to be your case), you have to add it [as mentioned here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text#fonts).

**Steps**

1. Download or Get the required fonts files and add them to the `res/fonts` directory.
2. Create `FontFamily` like this,

   ```
    val firaSansFamily = FontFamily(
        Font(R.font.firasans_light, FontWeight.Light),
        Font(R.font.firasans_regular, FontWeight.Normal),
        Font(R.font.firasans_italic, FontWeight.Normal, FontStyle.Italic),
        Font(R.font.firasans_medium, FontWeight.Medium),
        Font(R.font.firasans_bold, FontWeight.Bold)
    )
   ```
3. Use like this,

   ```
    Text(..., fontFamily = firaSansFamily, fontWeight = FontWeight.Light)
    Text(..., fontFamily = firaSansFamily, fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal)
   ```

Comment: Right, so I'm going to need to import the font file then, it's just not there for compose or in R.font.  Pretty lame they removed it.  Thanks for confirming.